# Can Ruby tell when a USB memory stick is plugged into a USB port on Linux?

Tags: ruby, linux, usb

I'm working on a utility that will scan USB ports and mount any Mass Storage devices it finds. I can poll for changes ( with a patched version of Ruby-USB ) but would much rather get a notification, or subscribe to some event.

Is there a way for Ruby to be tickled when a USB stick is inserted?

Comment: is there a reason you're writing such a utility instead of using something that does this already?  hotplug and/or udev come to mind...

Comment: You can use [libusb ruby](https://github.com/larskanis/libusb).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [ruby-dbus](http://github.com/mvidner/ruby-dbus). There is also a [tutorial](http://trac.luon.net/data/ruby-dbus/tutorial/intro.html) for it as well.

Comment: By that, I suppose you mean "listen for HAL events"?  That works, except that HAL is now deprecated (wow, that was fast ;-) and distributions are moving towards libudev instead.

Comment: The replacement for HAL is DeviceKit, which does essentially the same thing, except a) it's modular (HAL is a huge monolothic blob) and b) it only implements things that are not available from other libraries, unlike HAL which duplicates a whole bunch of functionality found elsewhere (like libudev). It is still based on D-BUS, though.

Comment: +1 to each of you. Good to know. Will keep in mind the next time I'm trying to pick up hardware notifications.

Comment: Precisely what I was looking for. Thanks.